# Which platforms are supported for adaptive Runtime platform?

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app

Which operating systems supported by adaptive.me and adaptive Runtime platform?

Jla

Answer (score 0):

Adaptime Runtime Platform currently supports:

- iOS => 8.0
- OS X => 10.10
- Android => 5.0
- Windows => 10

The JavaScript API is currently at v2.1.5 to ECMAScript 5 standard.

Hope this answers your question.